# _$CustomClass shows error of `The return type 'Type' isn't a 'CustomClass', as defined by anonymous closure. `

Tags: flutter

I have add a new class `TopicNew` and run `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` in to a sample code from [flutter_livestream_provider](https://github.com/tensor-programming/flutter_livestream_provider) for learning.

But I have no idea why my class shows error

```dart
import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';

part 'topicNew.g.dart';

abstract class TopicNew implements Built<TopicNew, TopicNewBuilder> {
  int get id;
  String get name;
  TopicNew._();
  factory TopicNew([updates(TopicNewBuilder b)]) => _$TopicNew;  #<- show error here
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a syntax error.

Instead of:

```dart
 => _$TopicNew;
```

do:

```
 = _$TopicNew;
```

---

Factory constructors can be declared as

```dart
factory Classname(int a) = OtherClass;
```

This syntax is a shorthand for

```dart
factory ClassName(int a) => OtherClass(a);
```

Comment: Do you know where this shorthand mentioned in dart document ? Thanks